# How to handle notifyjs click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifyjs

I would like to handle click events on the notification box by notifyjs, to link user to another page.

I understand that I could use jquery selector to select notifyjs class but that would break other notifications that are not meant to do the redirect.

I've look through notifyjs webpage and there's no click event documented.

How can I do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a different plugin like Noty? It has the ability to define callbacks so you can write cusom code.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, shall look into it